# My cpu won't turn on after some frequent power cut (load shedding)

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power

My computer won't turn on in general, but if I give it some time, say I wait for 2-3 hours and then press the power button, it works fine.

It was running perfectly until there was some frequent load shedding in my area and unfortunately I didn't use any UPS.

The problem is, when plug in my CPU and press the power button, nothing happens. I thought the power supply was causing the problem, but I tried connecting the GREEN and BLACK wire to test the power supply and both the power supply and the motherboard fans are running. I have also tried disconnecting the power button wires from the motherboard and connecting the pins manually, still no luck. But still if I wait for few hours and then press the power button, it works fine. I think there might be some capacitor in the motherboard that's not working, since giving some time solves the problem itself. Can anyone help me with it? Do I need to change the motherboard or something?

Comment: Your heatsink is fine? from when you are facing this issue.

Comment: I don't know if the heatsink is fine or not, but the fans in my cpu are running when it turns on. I faced the problem about a month ago for the first time. But then I didn't use the computer for few days and the problem was solved by itself. Yesterday, after some frequent power cut and some thunderstorm in my area (the power cable was plugged in to the wall socket), my cpu won't start. The power supply is okay. But the motherboard isn't posting to the power supply for some reason. If I wait for few hours, it works just fine.

Comment: Again if I shut down my computer, then unplug and plug it to the socket, it won't start. The motherboard won't post. Then if I wait for few hours, it works fine.

Comment: Can you see if the USB ports are giving out power when the fans are running, to check the 5V rail

Comment: Did you and notice any capacitor bulge on the mother board.